# How can I create overlapping groups for visualization?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'd likt to ask the way of grouping caategories. I knew that can use the Group function.

But my question is about duplicated values.

For example, There's column A,B,C,D,E in one table, but i want to make the bar graph as A, B&C, C&D ,E

Thank you for your time :)

I tried use group function, but since I group the Column B&C, It is not allow to gorup as C&D.

Comment: I made the title more specific, since the very point is the "grouping with overlaps". This was probably not understood by the person voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the following **calculated table** that contains your grouping logic

```
Groups = 
DATATABLE(
    "Group", STRING,
    "Category", STRING,
    {
        {"A", "A"},
        {"B & C", "B"},
        {"B & C", "C"},
        {"C & D", "C"},
        {"C & D", "D"},
        {"E", "E"}
    }
)
```

[image]

2. Next you create a one-to-many relation between the Categories with the filter direction set to "Both" (bi-directional)

[image]

3. Finally you can create your visuals with the overlapping grouping

[image]

Comment: If you prefer you can also do the first step in PowerQuery (instead of DAX) by simply entering the data in a table.